# Why does my innerHTML not return the array objects?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

Why is it I can get return a sorted array to my innerHTML but when doing the array objects I just get "[object Object],[object Object]" and how can I fix that?

Sorted Array

```
let vals1 = [8, 3, 2, 5, 4];
vals1.sort();

var numbers = document.getElementById("divPlaceHolder1");
numbers.innerHTML = vals1;
```

Result: 2,3,4,5,8

Objects in Array

```
let vals2 = [{
    x: 2,
    y: 10
},{
    x: 5,
    y: 6
}];

function compare(a, b) {
    return a.y - b.y;
}

var numbers2 = document.getElementById("divPlaceHolder2");
numbers2.innerHTML = vals2.sort(compare);
```

Result: [object Object],[object Object]
Expected: 0: {x: 5, y: 6}, 1: {x: 2, y: 10} this is what shows when doing vals2.sort(compare); in the browsers console.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" contant="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css" />
</head>    
<body>

        <div id="divPlaceHolder1"></div>
        <div id="divPlaceHolder2"></div>

    <script src="assets/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q2jn60u3/

Comment: use `JSON.stringify(obj)`.

Comment: The result is exactly what one would expect from the script. `.innerHTML` expects a string, `.sort()` returns an array. Therefor the browser calls `.toString()` on the array which then calls `.toString()` on its elements. And `.toString()` called on an object returns `[object Object]`

Comment: That said... Please add your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`var numbers2 = document.getElementById("divPlaceHolder");
numbers2.innerHTML = vals2.sort(compare);`

to

`var numbers2 = document.getElementById("divPlaceHolder");
numbers2.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(vals2.sort(compare));`

This should return your array of items.

```js
let vals2 = [{
    x: 2,
    y: 10
},{
    x: 5,
    y: 6
}]

function compare(a, b) {
    return a.y - b.y;
}

var numbers2 = document.getElementById("divPlaceHolder");
numbers2.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(vals2.sort(compare));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" contant="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>practice</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css" />
</head>    
<body>
    <div id="divPlaceHolder"></div>

    <script src="assets/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because objects are not a primitive data type and cannot be output directly by html. You would need to do something like JSON.stringify(vals2)

Comment: `JSON.stringify(vals2)`

Comment: Thanks that's what I meant